# Android - timestamp issue

Tags: android, iphone, timestamp

I've got a problem. I have closing data to display, app is get it from the cloud. The same data get version for iPhone.

On both platform time is different, because soon we will change time, so the iPhone app calculate this right, but not an Android one.

Timestamp:

1347145200000

Android - 8 September 2012

iPhone  - 9 September 2012

For example:
http://timestamptodate.com/?timestamp=1347145200
is showing the same like Android.

Which one is the right one and if it the iPhone app, how to fix this on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamp reads as Sept 8th 23:00 by UNIX standards. This is possibly a timezone or daylight saving time issue.

Comment: It working, great, I really don't know why I didn't think about it in first place. Thanks